# .NET Core Context inheritance IdentityDbContext with scaffold-dbContext command

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want the context that will be created in this scaffold command to inherit IdentityDbContext, not dbcontext. How can I specify it as inheritance? So

```
public partial class OrderSystemVContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, int>
```

I want it to be like this.

```
OrderSystemVContext : DbContext
```

is not like that.

Do I have to manually refresh it on every scaffold-dbcontext command?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement like this:
AppUser.cs

```
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {
    }
```

AppRole.cs

```
    public class AppRole: IdentityRole<int>
    {
    }
```

OrderSystemVContext.cs

```
    public class OrderSystemVContext: IdentityDbContext<AppUser,AppRole,int>
    {
    }
```

You will need to add the migration and update again when you change the context.

Comment: Well, when I do Scaffold-dbcontext, IdentityDbContext does not work, DbContext remains in the inheritance. Apart from these, when I do scaffold-dbcontext, if I do not specify a specific table, it also brings Identity's tables and saves them in the Context.

Comment: @Berat I thought it was code-first. I never saw built in method for db-first back to IdentityDBcontext. Maybe something like this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/using-aspnet-identity-objects-in-entity-framework-db-first  or this https://gavilan.blog/2021/06/25/mounting-identity-with-database-first-asp-net-core/. Is it worth of it? Better make a copy of the context code rather than regenerate.